# How to stop the algorithm version incrementing in beamer

Tags: beamer, algorithmic

I have an algorithm which I present in beamer. I want to add some text below it which appears on the second transition. However, the letter version for the algorithm  increments from A to B when the text below appears. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm}
\usepackage{default}

\makeatletter \def\fps@algorithm{H} \makeatother
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{\Alph{algorithm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Algorithm A}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Code}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State \Comment{\sc Empty array}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\vfill
\uncover<2->{
    Running time:   
    \[x^2\]
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

See how it is Algorithm A until the "Running time:" text below appears when it becomes Algorithm B.

How can I make it stay at Algorithm A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\resetcounteronoverlays{algorithm}` to your preamble:

[image: overlays]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm}
\usepackage{default}

\makeatletter \def\fps@algorithm{H} \makeatother
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{\Alph{algorithm}}
\resetcounteronoverlays{algorithm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Algorithm A}
        \begin{algorithm}
            \caption{Code}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                \State \Comment{\sc Empty array}
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
        \vfill
        \uncover<2->{
            Running time:   
            \[x^2\]
        }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. Yet another trivial LaTeX solution I am not sure I could have found without this site.